# What is the political system where there is a 'friendly' dictatorship

Tags: terminology

Is there a word for a kind of government where leadership is not elected, but the rulers are not harsh or violent? I am thinking of a 'just dictatorship', if you will.

Comment: See, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictatorship

Comment: This Q seems to be too broad. Consider, just for example: (1) someone may think that voting freedom is an ultimate rule, while harsh economic limitations can be bypassed; (2) often in dictatorships, the de-jure and de-facto laws/rules are very different to each other, which ones did you mean?

Comment: The problem is, how do you prevent oposition parties from having any influence without using violence ? Sooner or later oposition parties will appear (since the dictator is friendly it won't forbid them), and after years of being completely ignored, the opposition parties will start using violence themselves to be heard.

Comment: @Bregland I think it depends on your view of what qualifies as violence. For example, a dictator who is constrained by a 'just' written constitution might defend that constitution from violent democracy advocates who want mob rule (We can see one side of this scenario in Revolutionary France). If that constitution was just, then the 'violence' used by the dictator is not merely violence, but rather a just defence of good governance.

Comment: This is way too subject to opinion. What do you count as "friendly", and what do you count as a "dictatorship"? Some would say Putin's Russia would qualify, but others would say it's not a dictatorship, or say it's not friendly.

Comment: Since this question is just asking for a fairly common term, I voted to re-open it.

Comment: Having a desire for absolute power and control over a population tends to be at odds with "friendly."

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is Unicornian. People claim it exists, but no sightings have been verified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at Singapore under Lee Kwan Yew. Termed a "benevolent dictatorship".

Comment: [Lee's rule was criticised, particularly in the West, for curtailing civil liberties (public protests, media control) and bringing libel suits against political opponents. He argued that such disciplinary measures were necessary for political stability, which together with rule of law, were essential for economic progress.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Kuan_Yew)

Comment: The "benevolent dictator" is to political theory what the "[spherical cow in a frictionless vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow)" is to physics. An idealized mental construct which is used in theoretical models but doesn't exist in reality.

Comment: I don't know whether this is a UK v. US English issue, but the term I've heard most commonly is "benign dictatorship".

Comment: The Singaporean government is a viciously misogynist and anti-worker state; calling it "benevolent" reveals either an ignorance or acceptance of the oppression that happens.

Answer (score 2):

In Spanish (and at a lesser extent in Portuguese, Catalan and other romance languages) the word "[dictablanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictablanda)" (Port. ditabranda, Cat. dictatova, Fr. dictamolle) has been used.

In its original and still most common meaning it appeared in 1930 to mean the government of General Damaso Berenguer in Spain. That government followed the Primo de Rivera dictatorship and was an intent to preserve monarchy by somehow restoring the previous parliamentary system. Under Berenguer government civil liberties were more or less restored but elections weren't being called.

Then appeared the word "dictablanda" as a pun on "dictadura" ("dictadura"=dictatorship). The pun is that "dura"=hard and "blanda"=soft and it intended to convey the idea that Berenguer government was still a dictatorship despite of repression being way softer.

Although that is still the most common use, and "Dictablanda" is widely used to refer to the last year of Spanish monarchy in 1930-1931, even in scholar contexts, it has also been applied to other governments. As a quick Google search can confirm, it is mostly used in two kind of contexts:

- To criticise alleged authoritarian aspects on basically democratic regimes.
- To downplay the dictatorial aspect of actual dictatorships. For example, here is a video of [General Pinochet claiming his government in Chile was a "dictablanda" and not a "dictadura"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9coeJebFv08).

Interestingly, the same wordplay works in most romance languages but not in other linguistic families and hence the international but limited spread of the word.

Answer (score 1):

There is the word "[benevolent dictator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictatorship)". This word is a theoretical concept from Political Economics. According to wikipedia it can be traced back to John Stuart Mill's "On Liberty" (in the context of justifying European colonialism). The idea is that such a dictator acts for the general best: He knows what is best and implements it unobstructed by any group interested.

The title "[benevolent dictator for life](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_Dictator_for_Life)" has been applied for several highly-respected people in IT, e.g.:

- Richard Stallman (GNU project)
- Linus Torvalds (Linux)
- Guido van Rossum (Python)

The word "dictator" originally didn't imply harshness or violence, at least not necessarily. The Romans had quite a few dictators, some of them to save their Republic while a foreign army was standing in Italy or even at their city gates, but often a dictator's only office was to organize elections and would resign a few days later. "Dictator" was an honorable office; it was the title "king" ("rex") that sent shivers over a Roman's shoulders.

(The elections required the presence of a consul, but sometimes both consuls were leading an army too far away from Rome and could not be recalled. In such a situation, a dictator would have been named.)

Comment: The list of IT open projects "benevolent dictators" should also include Jimbo Wales for Wikipedia (https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator), although his role has changed a lot since that term was actually applicable.